# C++ program crashes with Linked List

Tags: c++, error-handling, linked-list

Hey guys I have problem with Linked Lists. My program crashes after I try to call function to search element in linked list. I am generating array and then tyring making linked list outta array elements. Now when i try to find 0 in linked list it crashes and I dont know why. Thanks for consideration

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

//ARRAY GENERATOR
int *gen_arr(int V[], int n, int dg, int gg){
srand(41);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    V[i]=1+(rand() % gg) ;
}
return V;
}

struct node{
int data;
node* next;
};

void SearchRecursive(node* Ptr, int number);
int main(){
int dg,gg;
int n=10;       
int* V = NULL;   
V = new int[n]; 

cout<<"Unesite vrijednost donje granice: "<<endl;
cin>>dg;
cout<<"Unesite vrijednost gornje granice: "<<endl;
cin>>gg;

V[n]=*gen_arr(V, n, dg, gg);
/*for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<V[i]<<" ";
}*/
node * nx = new node;
node* head = nx;
node* t = nx;
nx->data=V[0];
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
    nx = new node;
    nx->data = V[i];
    t->next = nx;
    t = nx;
}
nx->next=NULL;

t = head;
cout<<endl;
while(t != NULL){
    cout<<t->data<<" ";
    t = t->next;
}

cout<<endl;
cout<<"IIII"<<endl;
clock_t k;
k = clock();
SearchRecursive(head, 0);
k = clock()-k;
printf( "Vrijeme trajanja je %dms\n",k );   

return 0;
}

void SearchRecursive(node* Ptr, int number){
if(Ptr == NULL){
    cout<<"-1"<<endl;
}
else if(Ptr->data == number){
    cout<<"Pronadeno"<<endl;
}
else{
    SearchRecursive(Ptr->next, number);
}
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. A reproducible crash should be easy to debug. Use the debugger to step through your program and inspect variables and program flow along the way to see where they differ from your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your generator doesn't seem to be correct. Corrected version, return values in range [dg, gg):

```
//ARRAY GENERATOR
int *gen_arr(int V[], int n, int dg, int gg){
    srand(41);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        V[i]=dg+(rand() % (gg-dg));
    }
    return V;
}
```

Can you be more specific what input crashs your program?

Comment: Now problem is  node * nx = new node; and after. Firstly program ran all the way to the part where i printed out cout<<"IIII"<<endl; But now it crashes when i want to print nodes :/

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Ye generator is okay because i use lower range from 1 to  10 000. And now the program works just fine for 10 000 and 20 000 nodes no problem, but when I try to search list with 50 000 nodes it crashes , even tho program makes list and I cant figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the line:
`V[n]=*gen_arr(V, n, dg, gg);`
that can be translated as writing the value `V[0]` to `V[n]`, ie. out of bound of your array. Could result to a seg-fault or corrupt your program memory.
If you want copy your c-array, you should use `memcpy()`. And in your case, it's not necessary, as the argument `int V[]` of `gen_arr()` is a pointer to your array (and not a copy), so you are directly filling it from your for-loop.

Otherwise, no apparent reason your `SearchRecursive()` function is crashing... Then debugger is your friend.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, holidays :D 
I don't understand how V[0] to V[n] could be problem because in for loop there is contition  i<n  so it goes from 0 to n-1 . My program workd for 20 000 nodes but on 50 000 it crashes after it prints this line cout<<"IIII"<<endl;

Comment: On your line `V[n]=*gen_arr(V, n, dg, gg);`, your function `gen_arr()` is returning a `int*`.  
 So when you write `*gen_arr(...)` that is returning an `int`. And when you write `V[n]=value`, that is accessing to the nth coefficient of your array, that is obviously out-of-bounds.

Comment: Otherwise, what you said about your for-loop is correct. There is no issue about that. So you can try to replace your line `V[n]=*gen_arr(V, n, dg, gg);` by `gen_arr(V, n, dg, gg);` as simply. Its returned value doesn't matter as your are editing your `V` array directly from inside your function.

Comment: yea i get that and i replaced it , but as long as i play with the program it may be acessing already acessed adres and it crashes ?